# WordPress Featured Image Not In Div

Tags: image, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a featured image for a Custom Post Type that I am trying to lay out in a div. For some reason the image is on the page but outside the div. This is my first time working with featured images and custom post types. What am I missing that is causing the image to appear on the page before the div even starts?

```
if ($loop->have_posts()) {
    $output = '<div class="stories">';

    while($loop->have_posts()){
        $loop->the_post();
        $meta = get_post_meta(get_the_id());

        $output .= '
            <div class="story" style="float: left; display: block; border: 1px solid #CCC;">
                <a href="' . get_permalink() . '">
                    ' . get_the_title() . '</a>
                ' . the_post_thumbnail("medium") . '
                ' . get_the_excerpt() . '

            </div>
        ';
    }
    $output .= "</div>";
} else {
    $output = 'No Stories Added Yet.';
}

return $output;
```

When I view the HTML output this is what is rendered:

```
<div class="row-fluid ">
    <img class="attachment-medium wp-post-image" width="300" height="195" alt="13755721_m" src="http://code2media.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/13755721_m-300x195.jpg">
    <img class="attachment-medium wp-post-image" width="300" height="240" alt="African-Boy" src="http://code2media.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Snotty-African-Boy-300x240.jpg">
<div class="stories">
    <div class="story" style="flost: left; display: block; border: 1px solid #CCC;">
        <a href="http://code2media.net/stories/story-2/"> Story 2</a>
        Test Content
    </div>
    <div class="story" style="flost: left; display: block; border: 1px solid #CCC;">
        Test Content
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`the_post_thumbnail("medium")`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) is echoing the image thumbnail immediately when it is called, outside your other HTML as it is still being constructed, and appending an empty return value to your string. If you want the method to return the result to append to your string (you do), then you need to use [`get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, "medium")`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail)

Generally speaking, WordPress methods that start with `the_` will echo the result, and methods that start with `get_` will return the value.

Comment: Thanks. When I change it then nothing gets returned. It's like the call for the image is not even there.

Comment: Ahh, I had to add $post_id. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

the_post_thumbnail("medium") will return with img tag. you can get just featured image src and use as as want.

Take a look the [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src)

Comment: That's not correct, `the_post_thumbnail()` will echo the result `get_the_post_thumbnail()` will return it.